# click() assigned in document.ready in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do assignments in document.ready (*click(fn)* specifically) apply to newly appended elements that match the selector?

If not, how can I assign it to this new elements? Do I have to write the assignment after every append or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) functionality. Per the manual:

> Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and future - matched element. Can also bind custom events.

So if you do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.test').live('click', function() { alert('yipee!'); });
    $('body').append('<div class="test">Click me!</div>');
});
```

When you click on the div you will get the alert even though it was added after the event was bound.