# Attaching jQuery to buttons after document.ready

Tags: jquery

I'm writing some code based on the following article:

[jQuery - Dynamically Adding Form Elements](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/)

What I would like to do is to have buttons on each row to add a new row below the row the button is on.

This works OK for the first row, because there is code in document.ready to attach a jQuery function to the button.

However, the button in the second row is added dynamically - how do I attach the same function to this dynamically added button?

Thanks.

Matt.

Comment: Show us what you have already....

Comment: possible duplicate of [click() assigned in document.ready in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720057/click-assigned-in-document-ready-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use live() for dynamically added objects

instead of

```
$('.button').click(function(){});
```

use

```
$('.button').live('click',function(){});
```

> ```
> Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and
> ```
>
> future - matched element. Can also bind custom events.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

use function `live()`, this way it will bind events to created elements after document ready

Comment: Thanks - I marked Kanishka's comments as the answer because he gave more detail.  If I could mark you both as the answer, I would.

Answer (score 0):

From the JQuery docs...

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

on() function example:

$(selector).on(event,childSelector,function)